# In python regex, are character classes same as special sequences?

Tags: python, regex, terminology

From the documentation link here https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

> `[]` - (used to indicate a set of characters)
>
> - Character classes such as \w or \S (defined below) are also accepted inside a set

What are `character classes`? I am only familiar with `special characters` (`*`,`+`,`?`, etc) and `special sequences` (`\n`,`\r`,`\s`, etc). Do character classes refer to the latter `special sequences`? Or are they something different altogether? If so, what do `character classes` include exactly?

---

`character classes` appears only 2x in the entire page. It is poorly defined and does not indicate whether `\w`, `\S` are certain members of `character classes` or the only members. Further testing reveals that `\n` can also be used within `[]` but not something like `\A` - compounding the confusion.

Comment: "Character classes such as \w or \S (defined below)" have you tried scrolling down a bit?

Comment: character classes are a shorthand for a specific group of characters -- like digits, or alpha, or whitespace

Comment: @tobias_k character classes appears 2x in the entire page. It is poorly defined and does not indicate whether `\w`, `\S` are included or the only ones. testing reveals that `\n` can also be used within brackets but not something like `\A`. So yes. I already have tried scrolling down

Comment: [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) is a good place to begin with regex.

Comment: Sorry about that comment. Yes, it is a bit ill-defined, but at the same time it's rather intuitive, in my opinion. In short, "character classes" are groups of characters, such as "all whitespace" `\s`, "all numbers", `\d` or "all non-whitespace" `\S`, and are a subset of those "special sequences".

Comment: @tobias_k Am I lead to believe then that there is no comprehensive list defining what is supported and whats not? And that indeed `character classes` are a subset of `special sequences` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a bit ill-defined, but at the same time I think it's rather intuitive. In short, "character classes" are special characters, or "escape sequences" in the form `\...` representing groups of multiple characters, such as "all whitespace" `\s`, "all numbers" `\d`, or "all non-whitespace" `\S`, and are a subset of those "special sequences".

There are three character classes you should know:

- digits `\d`, corresponds to `[0-9]`; note that those do not match floating point numbers, as the `.` is *not* in `\d`
- "word"-characters, `\w`, corresponds to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but (in Python 2) does not include non-ascii characters, such as umlauts, accents, etc.
- whitespaces, `\s`, such as space, tabs, newlines, etc.

Also, each character class can be "inverted" by using the respective capital letter, i.e. `\W` matches everything that is *not* in `\w`, and similar for `\D` and `\S`.

Other "special sequences" comprise only a single character, such as newline `\n` or tab `\t` (although those are not really a part of the regex language, but just basic Python string escape sequences), and others represent abstract concepts such as "between a word and a non-word" `\b`, or "at the beginning of the string" `\A`.

Comment: About `\A`: does Python's regex flavour support the different meanings for `\A` and `^` (and, presumably, `\Z` and `$`)?

Comment: @RadLexus It seems like both `\A` and `^` match only the beginning of the string, and not the beginning of each line, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Thanks - sorry for the slightly off-topic comment, by the way, twas Idle Curiosity only ;)